# How to efficiently serialize python dict with known schema to binary?

Tags: python, dictionary, serialization

I have a lot of python dicts with known schema. For example, the schema is defined as Pyspark StructType like this:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
dict_schema = StructType([
        StructField("upload_time", TimestampType(), True),        
        StructField("name", StringType(), True),
        StructField("value", StringType(), True),
    ])
```

I want to efficiently serialize each dict object into byte array. What serialization method will give me the smallest payload? I don't want to use pickle because the payload is very large (its embedded the schema into each serialized object).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in `struct` module.  Simply "pack" the values:

```
import struct
struct.pack('Q10s5s`, time, name, value)
```

That's assuming time is a 64-bit int, name is at most 10 characters and value is at most 20 characters.  You'll need to tune that.  You might also considering storing the strings as null-terminated byte sequences if the names and values do not have consistent lengths (you don't want to waste space on padding).

Another good way is using [NumPy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html), assuming the strings have fairly consistent lengths:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.empty(1000, [('time', 'u8'), ('name', 'S10'), ('value', 'S20')])
np.save(filename, a)
```

This will include a "schema" of sorts at the top of the file; you could write the raw array without that schema if you really want to.

Answer (score 1):

i use `msgpack` (https://msgpack.org/) and order the dict values based on the sorted keys. i use `zip` to rebuild the keys with the packed values.

to my knowledge msgpack generally has comparable size performance as `struct`.

in terms of cpu performance, msgpack is 10x slower to encode and 50% slower to decode. msgpack natively handles many formats though, and can be extended with an encoding/decoding hook like JSON which makes things easier.

in terms of speed,...

```
import time
import msgpack
import struct

_time = int(time.time())
_keys = ('time', 'name', 'value')
_values = (_time, 'name', 'value')

as_msgpack = msgpack.packb(_values, use_bin_type=True)
as_struct = struct.pack('Q10s5s', _time, 'name', 'value')

def test_so_msgpack_encode():
    as_msgpack = msgpack.packb(_values, use_bin_type=True)
    return as_msgpack

def test_so_struct_encode():
    as_struct = struct.pack('Q10s5s', _time, 'name', 'value')
    return as_struct

def test_so_msgpack_decode():
    _decoded = msgpack.unpackb(as_msgpack)
    return dict(zip(_keys, _decoded))

def test_so_struct_decode():
    _decoded = struct.unpack('Q10s5s', as_struct)
    return dict(zip(_keys, _decoded))

print(timeit.timeit("test_so_msgpack_encode()", setup="from __main__ import test_so_msgpack_encode", number=10000))
print(timeit.timeit("test_so_struct_encode()", setup="from __main__ import test_so_struct_encode", number=10000))
print(timeit.timeit("test_so_msgpack_decode()", setup="from __main__ import test_so_msgpack_decode", number=10000))
print(timeit.timeit("test_so_struct_decode()", setup="from __main__ import test_so_struct_decode", number=10000))
```

In terms of speed, while there is a 10x factor... it's not likely going to be an issue.  I ran the above on a 10 year old (2008) computer to illustrate over 10000 iterations:

encoding:

```
0.0745489597321  # msgpack
0.00702214241028  # struct
```

decoding:

```
0.0458550453186  # msgpack
0.0313770771027  # struct
```

so it's possible to make it run faster with struct, but IMHO msgpack offers more.

note: the above isn't a perfectly equal test; I used the struct unpack above which appears to pad the value a few bytes. that could be fixed in the pack or unpack and would affect the result.